# Power BI AverageX

Tags: powerbi, average

I'm stuck!

I'm trying to work out the average of a column called 'Estimate Approval to Works Start' which is found on a table called 'ECM ClaimDates'.

I have another two tables, one is 'ECM Claims' and the other is _MyCalendar which is a date table.

The connections between all 3 are as follows.

ECM Claims and ECM ClaimDates have a relationship on a column called 'ref_number'.

ECM Claims has a relationship with the date table base on 'Closed_Date'

I want to use my calendar table in a visual table using a column called 'month year' and then return the average for each date/month for the column found in ECM Claim dates 'Estimate Approval to Works Start'.

Now i have managed to do this with regular average() function but it returns the incorrect average becuase there are duplicates found on ECM ClaimDates. I've been trying and trying but to no luck. How can this be done?

This is what I have so far

```
    Avg # Days For Estimate Approval to Works Start = 
CALCULATE(
AVERAGEX('ECM ClaimDates','ECM ClaimDates'[Estimate Approval to Works Start]),
NOT(ISBLANK('ECM ClaimDates'[Estimate Approval to Works Start])),
USERELATIONSHIP('ECM Claims'[claim_closed_date], _MyCalendar[Date])
)
```